# I want to find the difference between 2 lists of comma dilimited text files

Tags: file, awk, scripting, cmd, grep

I have 2 comma delimited text files.

File 1 contains a single comma delimited line

```
Brad@blah.com, jo@me.com.au, Josh@yahoo.co.uk
```

File 2 contains a single comma delimited line

```
George@here.com, brad@blah.com, sister@me.com.au, jo@me.com.au, josh@yahoo.co.uk
```

I want to display the email addresses that are in file 2 but not in file 1, so that the resulting file 3 would contain the text

```
George@here.com, sister@me.com.au
```

I have already been trying to find a solution with grep but any windows tools would be fine.

Comment: Why is it tagged bash if it is windows ?

Comment: both file have single line? can the file contain multiple lines? if yes, what would you do the filtering? per line? or per file? or what?

Comment: Sorry JID I thought I would lure some unix users who might have grep experience. Kent - hope the edit clarifies things.

Comment: Given that addresses come from human input, somewhere, there are going to be case variations in the data.  You really should smash everything down to lowercase and work from there with your solution.  As to the files having a single line - that's just plain odd.  If you were going to go for a Unix solution, then converting the files to multiple lines would yield a quick solution using normal command-line tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have multiple email addresses delimited by a comma surrounded optionally by spaces and tabs,

```
awk -F'[ \t]*,[ \t]*' 'NR == FNR { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) seen[tolower($i)] } NR != FNR { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if(!(tolower($i) in seen)) { print $i } } }' file1 file2
```

The awk code is

```
NR == FNR {                        # in the first file (overall line ==
                                   # line in file)
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {       # for all fields in the line:
    seen[tolower($i)]              # remember that you saw it.
  }
}
NR != FNR {                        # in subsequent files (here the second)
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {       # for all fields in the line:
    if(!(tolower($i) in seen)) {   # if you've not seen it before
      print $i                     # print it.
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** A simpler version adapted form @JID's comment is

```
awk -v RS='\n|[ \t]*,[ \t\n]*' 'NR == FNR { seen[tolower($0)] } !(tolower($0) in seen)' file1 file2
```

JID is correct that using the record separator can make the code simpler -- the for loops become unnecessary if the file is split into e-mail address records directly. I changed his record separator slightly to avoid introducing empty records between trailing commas and newlines, and to allow whitespace before commas.

This simplified approach works with `mawk` and `gawk`, which are the most common awks today. Nevertheless, regular expression record separators are not part of POSIX, so this may break on some old Unices.  In that case, refer to the first, non-simplified approach. That should work everywhere -- regular expression field separators *are* POSIX-conforming.

Comment: If you use RS instead of FS you can reduce this a bit `awk -vRS="\n|, *" 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)]++;next}!a[tolower($0)]'`

Comment: You should state that using a multi-char RS makes it gawk-specific (which is fine, just worth mentioning). For anyone without gawk, you could use `RS=,` and `{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "file3line="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28085343_file1.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (q28085343_file2.txt) DO (
  FOR %%s IN (%%b) DO (
   SET "found="
   FOR %%t IN (%%a) DO IF /i "%%s"=="%%t" SET found=Y
  IF NOT DEFINED found SET "file3line=%%s, !file3line!"
  )
 )
)
IF DEFINED file3line ECHO(%file3line:~0,-2%
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a files named `q28085343_file1.txt` and `q28085343_file2.txt` containing your data for my testing.